# Trouble understanding R's boot function

Tags: r, variance, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to use R's boot function to bootstrap a series of sensitivity indices that I have rolled up in a user-defined function.

Before using the boot function for the application mentioned above, I want to become familiar with the function and how it is used. From reading the description of the function boot, the data source may be a vector, matrix, or dataframe. If the data are a matrix or dataframe, the boot function will treat each row as a single multivariate observation.

Below is a simple example using the boot function to provide bootstrapped estimates of the variance for two columns of data.

```
library (boot)
#make a matrix who's rows are obs and columns are vbls
foo <- matrix (nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
set.seed (5280)
foo [,1] <- rnorm (100, 0, 1)
set.seed (5280)
foo [,2] <- rnorm (100, 10, 2)
apply (foo, 2, var) #for comparison to t0 in from the boot function
foo.var <- boot (data = foo, statistic = var, R = 1000, stype = "i",
                sim = "ordinary")
```

When I run the code above, I get very different answers for the variance of foo [,1:2]. Using the boot function, I get negative values (foo.var$t0).

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Thanks!

```
library (boot)
#make a matrix who's rows are obs and columns are vbls
foo <- matrix (nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
set.seed (5280)
foo [,1] <- rnorm (100, 0, 1)
set.seed (5280)
foo [,2] <- rnorm (100, 10, 2)

var.new <- function (x, ind){
    result <- var(x)
    return (result)
 }

apply (foo, 2, var.new) #for comparison to t0 in from the boot function
foo.var <- boot (data = foo, statistic = var.new, R = 1000, stype = "i",
                sim = "ordinary")
```

I reread the documentation and wrapped var up in the function var.new, which accepts the argument "ind". Now, I get the results I expect.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for what is expected of the `statistic` parameter?

Comment: Ah, yes - I reread the documentation. I modified the code by defining the following function: var.new <- function (x, ind){
  result <- var(x)
  return (result)
}
 adding the "ind" argument does the trick.